# Rating для каждой записи

Tags: php, html, jquery

Здравствуйте . Сделал рейтинг для каждой записи . Но проблема в том что при голосовании страница обновляется . Как можно сделать чтоб не обновлялось ? Понимаю что надо сделать с помощью ajax но как можете помочь ? Спасибо за внимание .

//Запись из db.php

```
function rate_up($id) {
    $sql = mysqli_query($this->connect(), "UPDATE `game` SET `up`=`up` +1  WHERE `id`='$id'");
    return $sql;
}
function rate_down($id) {
    $sql = mysqli_query($this->connect(), "UPDATE `game` SET `down`=`down` +1  WHERE `id`='$id'");
    return $sql;
}
```

//Запись из страницы записи

```
    $game = new db(); 

    if ($_GET['rate']== 'up'){
        $game->rate_up($id);
        echo "up";
    }
    elseif ($_GET['rate']=='down'){
        $game->rate_down($id);
        echo "down";
    }

 <div class="rate" style="background: #fff;">
    <a href="game.php?id=<?php echo $game_info['id']?>&rate=up"><img src="./like.png" /></a>
    <?php echo $game_info['up']?>

    <a href="game.php?id=<?php echo $game_info['id']?>&rate=down"><img src="./unlike.png" /></a>
     <?php echo $game_info['down']?>
    </div>
```

Comment: Могу помочь ссылкой на [документацию по jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

Answer (score 1):

Было:

```
<a href="game.php?id=<?php echo $game_info['id']?>&rate=up"><img src="./like.png" /></a>
```

Стало:

```
<a href="#" id="<?php echo $game_info['id']?>"><img src="./like.png" /></a>

//псевдо скрипт на jquery
<script>
  $('a').on('click',function () {
    $.get("game.php?id="+$(this).attr('id')+"&rate=up")
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь но не сработало

Comment: А что вы сделали? Покажите код. Ну и, разумеется, приведен код для голосования, а не отображения результатов. За вас тут код писать не станут, читайте любой гайд по ajax.

Comment: Я заменил старый код на новый